# Can I use T-test on the two data groups that are seperated from a big data group?

Tags: t-test

I am doing an experiment where participants will need to choose Yes or No at some point and then answer a question, let's say, their happiness, measured continually from 0 to 1.

Now, I split the samples into two groups based on this binary choice: a *Yes group* and a *No group*.

Then I want to check whether there is any difference in the happiness of the two groups.

My question is: **can I use t-test to do this?**

My guess is that it is NOT okay, because I would violate the pre-condition of *random sampling* by manually seperating them into a Yes group and a No group.

Comment: I would say that *t*-test is used this way commonly.  What you are assuming is that people who answered "Yes" are a random sample of all the people in some larger population that would answer "Yes".  ...  If you are only concerned with the population you have (say, the 50 people in your experiment), then you wouldn't need a hypothesis test, because you can calculate the actual mean of each group in your population.

Comment: As a thought experiment, can you think of a situation where you would use a t-test in the way you're describing?